# Access Universal Link app-argument in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I'm working on implementing Universal Links on our website, and I've run into a seemingly simple issue that I can't figure out. Searching Google and Stack Overflow hasn't helped, which leads me to believe I might just be missing something.

Basically, I'm adding the following to my page header (which has a URL of "https://www.website.com/slug").

`<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=xxx, app-argument=https://www.website.com/1" />`

Note that the `app-argument` has a different URL than the actual page.

I've setup my apple-app-site-association file properly. When I try and handle the Universal Link in our iOS app, I do this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard
        userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
        let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else
    {
        return false
    }

    // Set breakpoint here.
    return false
}
```

I set the breakpoint at the last `return false`, and when I inspect `components`, it contains the actual page URL ("https://www.website.com/slug") and not the URL passed in via `app-argument` ("https://www.website.com/id").

So my question is: How do I access the `app-argument` in my AppDelegate?